# Correct dimensions of X and Y for training a deep neural network in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a simple DNN with a dense layer in TensorFlow. I am having a hard time figuring out correct dimensions of X and Y to train a model in correct way.

The data is like this:

```
   X1  X2  X3   Y
0   1   2   3   1
1   4   5   6   4
2   7   8   9   7
3  10  11  12  10
```

I am fitting this data to a neural network as follows:

```
test_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape = (3,))
])
```

for fitting the data I have two chooses of Y dimension as Y1 and Y2:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
Y1 = np.array([[1],[4],[7],[10]])
Y2 = np.array([1,4,7,10])
```

TensorFlow won't complain about both `test_model.fit(X,Y1)` and `test_model.fit(X,Y2)`. But I observed that the loss and the training process is different. Which is correct and what is the difference between these two and what are the correct dimensions of X and Y to train a TensorFlow model in general.

Thank you for your answers.